# How to detect current slide number of carousel in react on ClassChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I want to detect the current slide number of the carousel when the slide changes.
How can I achieve it?. I was trying it with jquery but stuck on how to detect it on class Change.
Is there any other of achieving this other than jquery
For Carousel, I am using bootstrap.

Update:

The carousel slides are also on auto change after 5 secs interval

You can look at the code below.
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-sunset-ns3o1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3):

In Carousel, call a function with onSlide event.

```
<Carousel onSlide={setMovieKey} />
```

Then in your function, find the element with the active class name and then use elem.ID.

```
const setMovieKey = () => {
  const elem = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-item active')[0]
}
```

Comment: this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution with pure javascript:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [slideNo, setSlideNo] = useState(1);

  useEffect(()=> {
    function change(slide){
      setSlideNo(slides.indexOf(slide)+1)
    }
    let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');
    slides = [...slides];
    slides.forEach(slide => slide.addEventListener('transitionstart', () => change(slide)));

    return () => {
      slides.forEach(slide => slide.removeEventListener('transitionstart', ()=> change(slide)));
    }
  
  
  },[])
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        id="carouselExampleFade"
        className="carousel slide carousel-fade"
        data-ride="carousel"
      >
        <div className="carousel-inner">
          <div className="carousel-item active">
            <img
              className="d-block w-20"
              style={{ width: "100%", height: 400 }}
              src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/129208/pexels-photo-129208.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
              alt="First slide"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="carousel-item">
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              style={{ width: "100%", height: 400 }}
              src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/705164/computer-laptop-work-place-camera-705164.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
              alt="Second slide"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="carousel-item">
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              style={{ width: "100%", height: 400 }}
              src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1029757/pexels-photo-1029757.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
              alt="Third slide"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <a
          className="carousel-control-prev"
          href="#carouselExampleFade"
          role="button"
          data-slide="prev"
        >
          <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
          <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a
          className="carousel-control-next"
          href="#carouselExampleFade"
          role="button"
          data-slide="next"
        >
          <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
          <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <h4>Current Slide no. is {slideNo}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The carousel slides are also changing automatically after 5 secs

Comment: onClick will fail when the slides auto change after certain time interval

Comment: I have updated the solution. THis should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using `jQuery` alongside `react` defeats the purpouse of utilizing react in the first place. But I guess that the decision to use it was motivated by utilzing plain bootstrap library.
React components won't respond to changes made "behind the scenes" by bootstrap scripts. The actual state representing current slide is unreachable in this scenario and trying to hack it into the component would be very cumbersome if even possible.

I would suggest that you would switch to one of the `react` bootstrap libraries which are available out there:

- [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/)
- [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/carousel/)

This way you would have control over state representing current slide, because it would "live" within your `react` structure.

Comment: Really, just telling them to use the react library is a solution on how to get the react-library. Way to help!